# How to dynamically set the Row's text to bold, using MVVM, C# and no Code-Behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I'm developing a WPF Page using .NET, MVVM, no code-behind, using PropertyChanged. In this Page, I have a DataGrid with a lot of columns. 
Into the DB, one of the Columns, let's call it HIGHLIGHT, will have values S or N. If value = S, the entire line will be Bold, or ExtraBold. Case N = Normal.

I made this work using this code in XAML:

```
        <Style x:Key="TextRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" >
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Slab.Highlight}" Value="S">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="ExtraBold"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

But doing in this way, I'll have to put in EVERY COLUMN, this code to make it work (Notice the ElementStyle):

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Test" Binding="{Binding SlabSeq}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource TextRowStyle}"/>
```

What do I need:

Each table of my DB has several Columns, over 60, 70, and i'm searching for a way to make this more easy, like the StaticResource TextRowStyle i've made...

Another thing i've made, it was a Converter:

```
public class HighlightConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (System.Convert.ToChar(value).Equals("S"))
            return FontWeights.ExtraBold;
        else
            return FontWeights.Normal;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return FontWeights.ExtraBold;
    }
}
```

I'd tried to make a converter inside those fields, using:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <vm:HighlightConverter x:Key="HighlightConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

and into the Grid:

```
<TextBlock FontWeight={Binding Slab.Highlight, Converter={StaticResource HighlightConverter}}"/>
```

Does anyone have any idea of how I can make this work?

Best regards,
Gustavo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

why you dont create a "local" style in your DataGrid.Resources. did i get it right that the entire row has to be bold (S) or normal (N)?

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" >
     <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
     <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Slab.Highlight}" Value="S">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="ExtraBold"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

with the code above all cells would be normal, but if a datarow has Slab.Highlight=S all cells would be bold. the code is not tested. maybe you have to add TextBlock.Fontweight or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

What about applying the style implicitly by dropping the `x:Key`? That should make it apply everywhere in the grid when placed in the `DataGrid.Resources`.

Comment: I've tried that too, but doesn't work. That's why i've put that Style up the Page.Resources, it was another test.

Comment: @gustavosg: You are right, you would have to set the `ElementStyle` of the columns to `{x:Null}` for the implicit style to take effect...

Comment: i'm trying to set ElementStyle="{x:Null}" to that Datagrid. Instead of setting in every column, do you know how i can set to entire Datagrid?
When I do that, it shows me that error: {x:Type DataGridTextColumn} by blue line and said: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
That's because DataGridTextColumn does not derive from FrameworkElement (or FrameworkContentElement). Only FrameworkElement, supports styling. But I don't see a way to go through this.

Comment: @gustavosg: You cannot style the columns (i did not say otherwise), i just mean that the implicit `TextBlock` style only works if the `ElementStyle` of all the columns is nulled out. You can apply an implicit style to `DataGridCell` though, but then the `FontWeight` will also affect `TextBoxes` etc.

Comment: I was thinking, my intention was to style a grid's row, according to the rule , instead of set this style column to column. In this case, do you know how I can make this work?

Comment: @gustavosg: No, i do not. You could inherit from DataGrid and try all kinds of things though...

Answer (score 0):

This might work. Sorry, it's untested as I'm nowhere near an IDE.

```
            <DataGrid>
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridTextColumn">
                    <Style.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{Binding Slab.Highlight, Converter={StaticResource HighlightConverter}}"/> 
                        </Style>
                    </Style.Resources>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Well, i've tried this first, but the TargetType="DataGridTextColumn" isn't available. If I put "TextBlock" doesn't affect anything. If I put "DataGrid", and into Style.Resources put TargetType="TextBlock", only the Grid lines changes.

Comment: `but the TargetType="DataGridTextColumn" isn't available` how so?

Comment: I also found it strange, don't know why isn't available. However, it's available when i put this code into Page.Resources, not Datagrid.Resources.

Comment: Ah, I was wrong - DataGridTextColumn doesn't derive from FrameworkElement. GridCell is the better choice, as per the answer.